# c# Net Core method executes multiple times - multiple threads are created

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, thread-safety, dbcontext, lifetime

**The context:**

From javascript I make an ajax call to the controller to update entity "Owner". The controller uses a service to proccess the request, and update the entity acordingly. In the service update method I also update related data of "Owner", and in some cases I also add a new entity "Owner".

**The problem:**

Here(in the service), the update method gets called multiple times for some reason. Looking to the ThreadPool list, it shows multiple worker threads active. Because of this issue, I end up with multiple duplicated rows added and inconsistent data updated (some fields are missing - pants and jacket for example). I want it to run just once.

If i perform just an  EDIT operation nothing bad happens.

If I perform an ADD operation and then an EDIT operation, the edit will run 2 times, adding 2 more lines in the DB.

If I perform 2 or more(let's call this number N) ADD operations and then and EDIT operation, the edit will run for N x 2 times, creating N x 2 duplicated lines.

I minimized the code as much as I could. It is a bit long, but I didn't want to exclude any case that might actually be the culprit.

If the minimized code provided is not enough, I can also provide access to the repository for the code-wizzards among us. Please help me. I really don't know anything else i can try to make it work.

Stack used: .net core 2.2, latest jquery, mysql, pomelo, ef core

Stuff I already tried:

- async / await
- registering services and repositories in Startup as Scoped
- registering services and repositories in Startup as Transient
- registering the dbContext in startup as Transient
- threadPool.MaxLimit(1,1)
- js onClick / on ('click') / one ('click')
- all of the above combined

Frontend:

```
<script>
     $(document).one("click", "#buttonId", function () {
     $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
     var result = validator.validate(validator);
     if (result.formIsValid) {
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/controllerName/Edit",
        data: $('#editForm').serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            CloseModalById('editModal');
            ShowHeaderAlert(response, "success", 5000);
            $('#ownerListState').change();
        },
        error: function (error) {
            CloseModalById('editModal');
            swalErrorTimer(error.responseText, 7000);
        }
        });
       } else {
       updateUi(result.validationResults, "form-group", "error_span");
      }
      });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
    public OwnerController(IOwnerService ownerService,IMapper mapper)
    {
        _ownerService = ownerService;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public  ActionResult EditModal(OwnerViewModel ownerVM)
    {
        try
        {
            var dto = _mapper.Map<OwnerDto> ownerVM);
            var result = _ownerService.UpdateOwner(dto);
            if (result.Successful)
            {
                return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Successfully updated!"));
            }
            return BadRequest("Something went wrong!");
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
            Log.Error(e, "Something went wrong!");
            return BadRequest("Something went wrong!");
          }
    }
```

Service:

```
      public OwnerService(IOwnerRepository ownerRepository, ICatRepository catRepository, ICatService catService, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _ownerRepository = ownerRepository;
        _catRepository = catRepository;
        _catService = catService;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public Result<OwnerDto> UpdateOwner(OwnerDto ownerDto)
            {
                try
                {
                    var oldOwner = ownerDto.Copy();

                    // case: changed status in other than AtWork =>  empty the position for this set
                    if (ownerDto.LocationId != null && ownerDto.Status != "AtWork")
                    {
                        _catService.UpdateCatPosition(ownerDto.LocationId.Value, ownerDto.Biscuits, PositionEnum.InTheHouse);
                    }

                    // case: was AtWork, will be in raft => position changed
                    if (ownerDto.LocationId != null && ownerDto.Status == "AtWork" && ownerDto.LocationId != null && ownerDto.Biscuits == ownerDto.OldNrOfBiscuits)
                    {
                        _catService.UpdateCatPosition(ownerDto.LocationId.Value, ownerDto.Biscuits, PositionEnum.InTheHouse);
                        _catService.UpdateCatPosition(ownerDto.LocationId.Value, ownerDto.Biscuits, PositionEnum.InTheGarden);
                    }

                    // case: no change for position but change for nr of biscuits => 
                    if (ownerDto.LocationId != null && ownerDto.Status == "AtWork" && ownerDto.Biscuits != ownerDto.OldNrOfBiscuits && ownerDto.LocationId == null)
                    {
                        ownerDto.LocationId = ownerDto.LocationId;
                        // case we have added some new anv to this set => we have to also update the nr inside position
                        if (ownerDto.Biscuits > ownerDto.OldNrOfBiscuits)
                        {
                            var newNrBiscuits = ownerDto.Biscuits - ownerDto.OldNrOfBiscuits;
                            var catPosition = PositionEnum.InTheGarden;
                            _catService.UpdateCatPosition(ownerDto.LocationId.Value, newNrBiscuits, catPosition);
                        }
                        // case we have removed some biscuits from this owner => we have to also update the nr for the cat
                        if (ownerDto.Biscuits < ownerDto.OldNrOfBiscuits)
                        {
                            var newNrBiscuits = ownerDto.OldNrOfBiscuits - ownerDto.Biscuits;
                            var catPosition = PositionEnum.InTheHouse;
                            _catService.UpdateCatPosition(ownerDto.LocationId.Value, newNrBiscuits, catPosition);
                        }
                    }

                    // case: was AtWork, will be AtWork, Position changed, Biscuits changed

                    if (ownerDto.LocationId != null && ownerDto.Status == "AtWork" && ownerDto.LocationId != null && ownerDto.LocationId != ownerDto.LocationId && ownerDto.Biscuits != ownerDto.OldNrOfBiscuits)
                    {

                        var newNrBiscuits = ownerDto.OldNrOfBiscuits -(ownerDto.OldNrOfBiscuits - ownerDto.Biscuits);
                        var catPosition = PositionEnum.InTheGarden;
                        _catService.UpdateCatPosition(ownerDto.LocationId.Value, newNrBiscuits, catPosition);

                    }

                    // case: was not AtWork but will be AtWork
                    if (ownerDto.LocationId != null && ownerDto.LocationId == null)
                    {
                        _catService.UpdateCatPosition(ownerDto.LocationId.Value, ownerDto.Biscuits, PositionEnum.InTheGarden);
                    }



                    if (ownerDto.LocationId != null)
                    {
                        var catPosition = catRepository.GetPositionById(ownerDto.LocationId.Value);

                        if (!catPosition.Successful)
                        {
                            Log.Error("Something went wrong!");
                            throw new Exception("Something went wrong!");
                        }

                        ownerDto.CatPosition = _mapper.Map<CatDto>(catPosition);
                    }


                    //------------ Pants

                    var pants = _ownerRepository.GetPants(ownerDto.Pants);
                    if (!pants.Successful)
                    {
                        Log.Error("log stuff here");
                        throw new Exception("Something went wrong!");
                    }

                    if (Pants == null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ownerDto.Pants))
                    {
                        pants = _ownerRepository.AddPants(new DbModelPants() { Label = ownerDto.Pants.ToUpper() });
                    }

                    if (!pants.Successful)
                    {
                        Log.Error("log stuff here");
                        throw new Exception("Something went wrong!");   
                    }
                    ownerDto.pantsId = pants.Id;


                    ///////////////////// Jacket
                    var jacket = _ownerRepository.GetjacketByLabel(ownerDto.jacket);
                    if (!jacket.Successful)
                    {
                        Log.Error("log stuff here");
                        throw new Exception("Something went wrong!");     
                    }

                    if (jacket == null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ownerDto.Jacket))
                    {
                        jacket = _ownerRepository.Addjacket(new DbModelJacket() { Label = ownerDto.jacket.ToUpper() });
                    }

                    if (!jacket.Successful)
                    {
                        Log.Error("log stuff here");
                        throw new Exception("Something went wrong!");         
                    }
                    ownerDto.JacketId = jacket.Id;

                    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    var modelForDatabase = _mapper.Map<OwnerDbModel>(ownerDto);
                    
                    modelForDatabase.LastModified = DateTime.Now;

                    var value = _ownerRepository.UpdateOwner(modelForDatabase);
                    if (!value.Successful)
                    {
                        return Result<OwnerDto>.ResultError(value.Error);
                    }
                    var returnModel = _mapper.Map<OwnerDto>(value);

                    // if we move the biscuits we need to create a new owner with the remaining biscuits values that were not moved to the new location
                    //--------- This adds a new Owner to the db with oldData
                    if (oldOwner.OldNrOfBiscuits > oldOwner.Biscuits && oldOwner.LocationId != oldOwner.LocationId && oldOwner.LocationId != null && oldOwner.LocationId != null)
                    {
                        oldOwner.Biscuits = oldOwner.OldNrOfBiscuits - oldOwner.Biscuits;
                        oldOwner.LocationId = oldOwner.LocationId;
                       
                        oldOwner.Id = 0;

                        var addedOldSet = AddOwner(oldOwner, PositionEnum.AtThePetStore);

                        if (!addedOldSet.Successful)
                        {
                        Log.Error("log stuff here");
                        throw new Exception("Something went wrong!");       
                        }
                    }

                    return Result<OwnerDto>.ResultOk(returnModel);

                }
                catch (Exception er)
                {
                    Log.Error("log stuff here");
                    throw new Exception("Something went wrong!");      
                }
            }


     public Result<OwnerDto> AddOwner(OwnerDto owner, PositionEnum catPosition = PositionEnum.InTheGarden)
    {
        try
        {
            if (owner.LocationId != null && owner.Status == "AtWork")
            {
                var catPosition = _catService.GetPositionById(owner.LocationId.Value);
                if (!catPosition.Successful)
                {
                    Log.Error("log stuff here");
                    throw new Exception("Something went wrong!");          
                }

                _catService.UpdatePosition(owner.LocationId.Value, owner.NrBucati, catPosition);
               
                catPosition = _catService.GetPositionById(owner.LocationId.Value);
                owner.CatPosition = catPosition;
            }
            //------------ Pants
            // if we don't find the pants with provided name in the table Pants, we add a new set of Pants and provide the Owner with that set. Same for the Jacket.
            var pants = _ownerRepository.GetPants(ownerDto.Pants);
            if (!pants.Successful)
            {
                Log.Error("log stuff here");
                throw new Exception("Something went wrong!");
            }

            if (Pants == null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ownerDto.Pants))
            {
                pants = _ownerRepository.AddPants(new DbModelPants() { Label = ownerDto.Pants.ToUpper() });
            }

            if (!pants.Successful)
            {
                Log.Error("log stuff here");
                throw new Exception("Something went wrong!");   
            }
            ownerDto.PantsId = pants.Id;

            //----------- Jacket
            var jacket = _ownerRepository.GetjacketByLabel(ownerDto.Jacket);
            if (!jacket.Successful)
            {
                Log.Error("log stuff here");
                throw new Exception("Something went wrong!");     
            }

            if (jacket == null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ownerDto.Jacket))
            {
                jacket = _ownerRepository.Addjacket(new DbModelJacket() { Label = ownerDto.jacket.ToUpper() });
            }

            if (!jacket.Successful)
            {
                Log.Error("log stuff here");
                throw new Exception("Something went wrong!");         
            }
            ownerDto.JacketId = jacket.Id;

            var modelForDatabase = _mapper.Map<OwnerDbModel>(owner);
            modelForDatabase.LastModified = DateTime.Now;
            modelForDatabase.Name = modelForDatabase.Name.ToUpper();

            // send model to database
            var addedOwner = _ownerRepository.AddOwnerToDatabase(modelForDatabase);
            var returnModel = _mapper.Map<OwnerDto>(addedOwner);
            return Result<OwnerDto>.ResultOk(returnModel);

        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            Log.Error("log stuff here");
            throw new Exception("Something went wrong!");         
        }
    }
```

The update and add methods inside all repositories are similar. Example:

```
    public Entity UpdateEntity(Entity entityToUpdate)
    {
          _db.EntityDbSet.Update(entityToUpdate);
          _db.SaveChanges();
          return entityToUpdate;
    }
    
    public Entity AddEntity(Entity entityToAdd)
    {
          _db.EntityDbSet.Add(entityToAdd);
          _db.SaveChanges();
          return entityToAdd;
    }
```

Comment: The thread pool threads don't have anything to do with your problem; just ignore them. 1) Only call `SaveChanges` once per HTTP request. 2) Do some reading on "optimistic concurrency".

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary I will do some reading into that.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in the HTML file. The partial view that contained the modal also loaded the js file and because of that it loaded it multiple times. That is where the multiple calls came from. To make it work I loaded the js file in Index. Such a simple solution for a crazy problem with crazy results...